# Symfony easy admin Bundle setting/assigning user roles

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, easyadmin

I am trying to configure the easy admin configuration.

Here is my database structure wiht the user.

```
user (Table)
_____
id
username
password
email
```

Now when i try to logg in, i understand that the construct wants/need some kind of user role. 
Since this error comes up

> Argument 3 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Token\PostAuthenticationGuardToken::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in \AbstractGuardAuthenticator.php on line 37

So my question is how do i assign my user a Role ?

Here are my configs.

In my `security.yml` File i have these configs.

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory: { memory: null }
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\AuthAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            # where to redirect after logout
            # target: app_any_route

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
     - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

And my `easy_admin.yml` is empty.

If there is any other information you need, let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Do the user have a role when they register?

Comment: There is no registration, i just add them to the database.

Comment: Just add ["ROLE_USER"] in field role in the database

Comment: I dont have a role field... that's the catch. I Auto generated the Table and i did not get any role field.

Comment: That is strange with `php bin/console make:user` the field role should be created automaticly

Comment: The only thing i have is a getRoles() function in my User Entity which just Has     
 ```// TODO: Implement getRoles() method.```

Comment: `/**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You should add the "roles" property to the `User` table as stated at the Symfony security documentation:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles